# useFormContext() is null but its context state exist. How can I get it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-hook-form, react-admin

Currently `react-admin: ^4.8.3` / `react-hook-form: 7.40.0`.

I have the following code:

```
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'

const MyComponent = () => 
{
  const {formState: {isValid}} = useFormContext()
  // provoke a crash as useFormContext() is null
  return <></>
}
```

```
import {
  SimpleForm,
  TextInput,
  maxLength,
  required,
} from 'react-admin'

const FooForm = () => {
  return (
    <SimpleForm
      mode="all"
      reValidateMode="onChange"
      toolbar={toolbar}
      onSubmit={save}
    >
      <TextInput
        label="resources.resourceName.fields.name"
        source="name"
        validate={[required(), maxLength(50), noEmptySpace]}
      />
      <MyComponent/>
    </SimpleForm>
  )
}
```

`useFormContext() = null` and its deconstruction provoke a crash.

Using React Context Devtool I know that the context exist with the name `debugId_${randomNumber}` with the right updated values and the form state like isValid.

[image: form context using React Context Devtool]

How can I fix `useFormContext()` being null or access this unnamed react context by another way ?

I tried to use `useFormState` but it require field `control` that I cannot have access, or it is from a useless empty new `useForm()`.

I also tried to use `useContext(FormGroupsContext)` but it only has functions to register fields and does not have state or context names.

For those who are asking, react-admin `SimpleForm` use react-admin `Form` which use `FormProvider` that should pass its context to children. I should not have `useFormContext() = null`.

How can I fix useFormContext() being null or access this unnamed react context by another way ?

Comment: From where you import useFormContext?

Comment: it is from react-hook-form `import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'`

Comment: Are you sure that this MyComponent causes the crash? If you remove it from FooForm 
does the error still exist? What does console.log(useFormContext()) gives you?

Comment: My best guess is you have two separate versions of `react-hook-form` installed, one being used by `react-admin`, the other by your own code. Since they're separate versions, they'll have separate hooks and "cross-using" them doesn't work. If you're using `yarn` as your package manager, check `yarn why react-hook-form`...

Comment: `console.log(useFormContext())` return `null`. I use npm and only have version 7.40.0 in both `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Comment: Can you check what useFormState() gives you, from react-hook-form

Comment: `useFormState()` crash. `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')`. And I cannot get `control` because it is only accessible from `useFormContext()` or a newly created `useForm()`

Comment: I don't see any issues. Can you try to update react-hook-form to the latest version

Comment: I updated rom 7.40.0 to 7.44.2 and it still return `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was right from the beginning, the issue was that since my project was old, I had an old webpack with lots of babel and config override that completly broke this exact context.
I migrate my project to use vitejs and everything is fine now !